# how to display multple columns in listview columns?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, listview

is it possible to display the two database column in one row column in listview in vb.net using mysql.data.mysqlclient?

```
 Listview:              where in database:
 ---------------            *Firstname: John
 |  Full Name  |            *Lastname: Smith
 |_____________|
 |             |
 |  John Smith |
 |_____________|
```

here's my code:

```vb
For i = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
    With lvlistview
        .Items.Add(table.Rows(i)("dte"))
        With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
            .Add(table.Rows(i)("tran_no"))
            .Add(table.Rows(i)("comp_type"))
            .Add(table.Rows(i)("status"))
            .Add(table.Rows(i)("sys_name"))
            .Add(table.Rows(i)("mod_name"))
            .Add(table.Rows(i)("err_desc"))
            .Add(table.Rows(i)("trigg"))
            .Add(table.Rows(i)("fname" . "lname")) **How i gonna combine this two database column in only one listview column**
        End With
    End With
Next
```

Comment: How are you populating the listview control?  With data-binding?  Is this a WinForm, ASP, WPF project?

Comment: it's winform sir. how i gonna do this? put two database column in one listview column?

Comment: How are you populating the listview control?  Are you using data-binding, or are you manually adding the items with your own code?

Comment: i manually adding the items in my own code sir.

Comment: Can you show that part of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to concatenate the values from the two DB columns together.  If you were using data-binding, the simplest solution would be to alter your SQL command so that the values are concatenated by the DB engine and returned to you as a single column.  However, since you are adding the items yourself, you can, alternatively, just concatenate the two columns in your code before adding the item to the `ListView`, for instance:

```
With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
    .Add(table.Rows(i)("tran_no"))
    .Add(table.Rows(i)("comp_type"))
    .Add(table.Rows(i)("status"))
    .Add(table.Rows(i)("sys_name"))
    .Add(table.Rows(i)("mod_name"))
    .Add(table.Rows(i)("err_desc"))
    .Add(table.Rows(i)("trigg"))
    .Add(table.Rows(i)("fname") & " " & table.Rows(i)("lname"))
End With
```

The `&` character is the standard string-concatenation operator in VB.NET.  You can also use the `+` operator, but you have to be more careful of your type casting when you use the `+` operator with strings.  Since the `&` operator is a little safer and it's slightly more self-documenting, it's typically the preferred operator for strings.

For more complicated concatenations, you may also want to consider using `String.Join`, `String.Format` or the `StringBuilder` class.

Comment: THANK YOU SIR!!!!! it worked!! thank you so much. i have one last question. do you know how to left join in listview using winform?

Comment: The easiest thing would be to do the left join in your SQL command, then you'll have access to the joined columns via the `table` variable, just like the other columns.  Alternatively, you could execute two separate SQL commands to get the data into two separate data tables, then you could use both data tables to populate each `ListView` item.